# google map addlistener onclick get xml data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary

hi I have problem with addlistener in google map
I cant get html value from xml. always return [object Element]

```
   document.getElementById("infobox").innerHTML = html;
```

and      infowindow.setContent(html); work perfectly

I know I do this before last 1 month ago i dont know was v3 version or this. but i do this before!

or if you know other way for getting out data please help!

from this code in addlistener

```
  var side_bar_html = " "; 

  var html = " "; 

  var gmarkers = []; 

  var map = null;
```

/

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
var contentString = html;


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5,icon : 'mark.png'

    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
           document.getElementById("infobox").innerHTML = html;
    infowindow.setContent(html); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

    });



gmarkers.push(marker);
// add a line to the side_bar html
side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';


}




function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");

}

   function initialize() {

   var myOptions = {
   zoom: 11,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.06106741381199,46.359741),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

  // Read the data from example.xml
  downloadUrl("example.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("infowindow")[0]                  ;
      var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
      // create the marker


      var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
    }



           document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;



    // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div

  });





   }


 var infowindow = new google.maps.


InfoWindow(
 { 
   size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
 });
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<maincontent>
<markers>
<marker lat="37.95989919257204" lng="46.38427734375" label="way 1">
  <infowindow>station 1</infowindow>
</marker>
</markers>
</maincontent>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including a sample of any required XML.

Comment: xml works fine but added

Answer (score 0):

I found what is problem just change tag to attribute!

```
 var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
```

But I dont know why!